How to resolve Cannot find name 'NgxMatDatetimePickerModule'. Did you mean 'MatDatepickerModule'?
I am migrating my project to Angular 18.1 from Angular 9.1 but I'm facing the Cannot find name 'NgxMatDatetimePickerModule'. Did you mean 'MatDatepickerModule'?ts(2552) error in AppModule
I think the error is likely occurred due to ngx-mat-datetime-picker package is not compatible with Angular 18.1, Is there any way to resolve this error

I checked the package reference for ngx-mat-datetime-picker and it's deprecated, you need to instead use angular-material-components, which seems to work fine.
<input
  matInput
  [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="$any(picker)"
  placeholder="Choose a date"
/>
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="$any(picker)"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker> </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>

But you should note that the styles are not applied when we use the legacy material 15 styles or angular material 18 (material styles). If you are ok with styling the datepicker yourself, then go for it.
Stackblitz Demo
